# How to read file until a specific element

Tags: java

I'm facing a problem that I can't (more likely I don't know how to) read a file until a specific element.
My file looks like:

```
Vaga 
Senieji Amatai, 2016, 5,4
Humanitas 
Kolumbas, 1980, 3
Programavimas Java, 2016, 14,56
```

And any ideas how to stop it reading at 5,4?

Here's a little part of my code:

```
File FILE = new File(duomenuFailas);
if (FILE.exists() && FILE.length() > 0) {
    try {
        Scanner SC = new Scanner(FILE);
        for (int i = 0; i < FILE.length(); i++) {
            if (SC.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] parodyti = SC.nextLine().split(",");
                System.out.println(parodyti[0]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `length()` gives the number of bytes, not the number of lines.

Comment: Ahm, I just need go through the lines thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
    File file = new File(duomenuFailas);
    if (file.isFile()) {
        try {
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String[] parodyti = sc.nextLine().split(",");
                    System.out.println(parodyti[0]);
                    if (parodyti[0].equals(stopElement)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```